# Class of lattices that excludes $M_3$?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-theory

It is well known that a lattice is distributive iff it excludes as a sublattice $N_5$ (the pentagon) and $M_3$ (three unordered elements with a top and bottom). Further, a lattice that only excludes $N_5$ is modular, and consequently a lattice excluding $N_5$ but including $M_3$ is modular but not distributive.

What, if anything, is known about the class of lattices that excludes $M_3$? Does it relate to classes of structures of any particular interest? (Note this is not the same as asking about "nonmodular varieties", since those are varieties which *include* $N_5$).

Comment: I found this question while looking for *any* studied/natural classes of lattices which are not distributive, and which also do not contain $M_3$ (i.e. not necessarily the class all lattices which avoid $M_3$). For anyone else looking for this type of thing: two classes of lattices with this property are join semi-distributive lattices, and meet-distributive lattices. See Paul H. Edelman, Meet-Distributive Lattices and the Anti-Exchange Closure, or for more information one could start at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.01528.pdf

Answer (score 15):

This is a (slightly edited) copy of the answer I posted on math.SE to the question [What do we call a lattice that does not have a sublattice the shape of the diamond $M_3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608854/what-do-we-call-a-lattice-that-does-not-have-a-sublattice-the-shape-of-the-diamo):

> Let $\mathbf K$ be the class of all lattices not containing $M_3$ (the $5$-element nondistributive modular lattice) as a sublattice; in other words, lattices in which every modular sublattice is distributive. It is easy to see that $\mathbf K$ can be characterized as the class of all lattices satisfying the following sentence $\varphi$:$$\forall u\forall v\forall a\forall b\forall c[(ab=ac=bc=u)\wedge(a+b=a+c=b+c=v)\rightarrow(u=v)]$$or equivalently$$\forall a\forall b\forall c[(ab=ac=bc)\wedge(a+b=a+c=b+c)\rightarrow(ab=a+b)]$$ or
> $$\forall a\forall b\forall c[(ab=ac=bc)\wedge(a+b=a+c=b+c)\rightarrow(a=b)].$$
> Inasmuch as $\varphi$ is a universal Horn sentence, it follows that $\mathbf K$ is closed under taking sublattices, direct products and reduced products; it is a [quasivariety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasivariety).
>
> On the other hand, $\mathbf K$ can not be characterized by identities, and is not closed under taking homomorphic images. Bjarni Jónsson [[Sublattices of a free lattice, Canad. J. Math. 13 (1961), 256-264](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/sublattices-of-a-free-lattice/0C337979E256458AFA14321F6785707E), Lemma 2.6(i)] observed that, as a corollary of P. M. Whitman's work, elements $u,a,b,c$ of a free lattice satisfy the condition: if $u=ab=ac$, then $u=a(b+c)$. It follows that $M_3$ is not a sublattice of a free lattice, i.e, the class $\mathbf K$ contains all free lattices. Thus every lattice is a homomorphic image of a member of $\mathbf K$, and every identity which holds in all $M_3$-free lattices is a consequence of the lattice axioms. In view of this, we are not likely to find a much simpler algebraic characterization of $M_3$-free lattices than the one in the previous paragraph.

Comment: This is very nice, thanks! I have another argument that follows from covers of varieties that shows this is not a variety, which is why I wrote "class" and not "variety". I was wondering if it had been considered in any literature nonetheless. I'll leave this open in case anyone has an answer to that, but I do appreciate this answer as nice and clean.

Comment: Not a variety, but it is a quasivariety.

Answer (score 10):

As bof says, the class $\mathcal K$ of lattices omitting $\mathbf M_3$ as a sublattice is a quasivariety that is not a variety. As bof also says, this implies that $\mathcal K$ is closed under the formation of sublattices, products, and reduced products, but the class is not closed under the formation of homomorphic images.
But $\mathcal K$ is closed under some types of homomorphic images.

A. (Projection onto a direct factor)
If $L\times L'\in \mathcal K$, then $L, L' \in \mathcal K$. Every quasivariety of lattices has this property, but there exist quasivarieties of algebraic structures that do not have this property.

B. (Quotients of finite members) If $L\in \mathcal K$ is finite, then any homomorphic image of $L$ is also in $\mathcal K$. This property typically fails for quasivarieties, even quasivarieties of lattices. It holds for $\mathcal K$ because $\mathbf M_3$ is projective in the class of finite lattices.

Comment: I guess A holds because $L$ and $L'$ are sublattices of $L\times L'$ because lattices have trivial sublattices. B seems harder. Is there a literature about $\mathcal K$? Does it have a name?